# WinForms Retrieve Keyboard State without Form/UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, keyboard

I'd like to retrieve the state of the `Ctrl` keys in a place where I don't have a form.

Normally to get a key state I'd use Control_KeyDown / KeyUp events. However, the code that needs to know whether Ctrl is pressed is outside any form. There is a form displayed, but the code is supposed *not* to depend on that form but finding the key state on its own.

Surely there is a way to do that, only I don't succeed to find it on google.

Note that although the code doesn't "have" a form available, its still a WinForms application, so maybe the framework provides some class/object for me to achieve that goal.

**Background:**

During the application startup phase, I want one step to behave differntly if the Ctrl key is being pressed in that moment. The startup phase displays a splash screen, but the code for the startup isn't aware of that. Instead it reports progress to a callback, and that callback updates the splash screen.

If I use the splash screen for fetching the KeyDown event, I make the startup code depend on that splash screen, which introduces a circular dependency. I want to keep the freedom to remove the splash screen and replace by something different.

Comment: Does this mean that your application needs to know if Ctrl is clicked regardless which application is the active one? So if your working in any program and click Ctrl, you want your program to catch it? In that case it's a keyboard hook you are after. If you confirm this, I can give you a few pointers.

Comment: @Øyvind: It's not necessary to notice Ctrl if another application is in front. In fact it would even be better if Ctrl is *not* registered in that case (see my update about the background of my question).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use the static method on `Control` called `ModifierKeys`

[Control.ModifierKeys on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.modifierkeys.aspx)

eg:

```
if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Control)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: I tried this a couple of days ago and it didn't work, because at this stage (initialization with splash screen) the event loop wasn't running yet. (See also comment to testalino). Now the splash screen runs in a message loop, and the solution works.

Answer (score 3):

I've done exactly that just recently:

```
    static class NativeMethods
    {
        public static bool IsControlKeyDown()
        {
            return (GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) & KEY_PRESSED) != 0;
        }
        private const int KEY_PRESSED = 0x8000;
        private const int VK_CONTROL = 0x11;
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern short GetKeyState(int key);
    }
```

To test the code, create a new Console Application and use the following main method:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(NativeMethods.IsControlKeyDown());
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I couldn't find any non-native solutions a couple of days ago.

Comment: @testalino: I've copied and pasted your code, and added a call to IsControlKeyDown(), but it returned false even if I press both Ctrl keys.

Comment: @chiccodoro I've created a test application and it works here, I'll edit my answer with the test code.

Comment: @testalino: That's probably my fault! The event loop only starts after the initialization, what's not recommended and probably why I don't get the event...

Comment: My code is not event based - it is poll based. You need to check whether the key is pressed. If you need events, you must create a keyboard hook.

Comment: @chiccodoro so you created an empty console application in Visual Studio with the test code i provided and when you press ctrl while the code runs you don't see the value changing to true? I can assure you that this code works.

Comment: @testalino: No, I haven't tried this, I only tried it in my application. I believe you that it'll work in a empty console application, but that doesn't help me. That's why I say I don't understand why it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just catch the `Ctrl` being pressed on the form that *is* displayed, since it seems that this form is also a part of the appication, and relay the click to the "formless" part of the code using an event that the form can invoke?

I might misunderstand what you are after here, but it seems like an option at least.

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking about this approach too. However in my case it introduces a dependency which I'd rather prevent (see update on my question).